# How to link domain with EC2 and SSL

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

Here is my story

1. I have Amazon EC2 with Tomcat 7 hosted at an Elastic IP as

http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-X.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/webAppX

http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-X.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/webAppY

http://ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-X.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/webAppZ

2. Then I bought a domain at 1&1 as domainXYZ.com
3. I bought SSL from sslmate.com for the domainXYZ.com

Now, my confusions come

1. We follow instructions from sslmate.com and do the same for httpd from Amazon EC2 but when I access http**s**:// , the browser says errors as below

   Your connection is not private
   Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

   This server could not prove that it is ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com; its security certificate is from www.domainXYZ This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection. Learn more.

Could you please advice me what things I missed or wrong.

Question #2: How come I re-direct from 1&1 to ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com?

I do see we have options such as FramRedirect, or A record by changing DNS using IP

But I'm not sure which one I should use for HTTPS will be handled.

Thanks,
Nghia

Answer (score 0):

You are making your life unnecessary difficult.

Just buy the domain using [AWS Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/de/route53/) and link it to your Elastic IP.

As soon as your instance is reachable via the domain set up a certificate for free using LetsEncrypt and [EFF's certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

Finally open HTTPS port via AWS console security settings.

Comment: Thanks Raffael, but again I need to pay domain fee if I want to use Route53. Moreover I'm asking here to see why I getting certificate error. Please advice. I'm very new with Amazon EC2 and SSL